# Rounding a number down in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

I have a Visual Basic application that needs to round a number down, for example, 2.556 would become 2.55 and not 2.26.

I can do this using a function to strip off the characters more than 2 right from the decimal point using this:

```
Dim TheString As String
TheString = 2.556
Dim thelength = Len(TheString)
Dim thedecimal = InStr(TheString, ".", CompareMethod.Text)
Dim Characters = thelength - (thelength - thedecimal - 2)
_2DPRoundedDown = Left(TheString, Characters)
```

Is there a better function to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx).  However, you'll need to multiply * 100 and divide, since you can't supply a number of digits

```
Dim theNumber as Double
theNumber = 2.556
Dim theRounded = Math.Sign(theNumber) * Math.Floor(Math.Abs(theNumber) * 100) / 100.0
```

Comment: Sometimes it's beneficial to store your numbers as integers, or fixed-point (if you don't need the full range of floating-point), performing calculations on the fixed-point numbers and then adjust them when displaying to the user.

Comment: @Justin: Good point - I edited to account for negative numbers, as well as positive

Comment: Since this is VB, just use a Currency datatype.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it that doesn't rely on using the String type:

```
Dim numberToRound As Decimal
Dim truncatedResult As Decimal
numberToRound = 2.556
truncatedResult = (Fix(numberToRound*100))/100
```

Comment: Using Fix() will be slightly faster than using Floor().

Comment: Do you anything that supports that statement?

Comment: @Justin: Fix is actually slower than Math.Floor - it does a check, then calls Math.Floor internally.  Run reflector on Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll for details.

Comment: Whoops I said it backwards. Your comment was my rationale.

Answer (score 2):

The Math.Floor( ) answer is good.  I'm not sure exactly which VB environments Fix( ) is defined in.  As Justin points out, Math.Floor( ) won't work with negative numbers.  You'd have to take the absolute value, then multiply by the SGN( ) of the number.  I don't know the exact name of the function that you'd use to get the SiGN (not sin() ) of the number.

In pseudo-code, taking negative values into account, the result would looks like:

```
result = sgn( num ) * floor( abs( num * RoundToDig ) ) / RoundToDig
```

-- 
Furry cows moo and decompress.

Comment: I am used to the Fix() function from VB6, but it is available in VB.NET as well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.fix.aspx

Comment: @WyrdestGeek:  The function is Math.Sign.    @Saul: Fix calls Math.Floor internally.

Comment: What is this business about decompressing bovines?

Answer (score 1):

To round down

```
Math.Floor(number)
```

To trim characters

```
number.Substring(0,1)
```

You can convert it to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Input As Decimal
Dim Output As Decimal
Input = 2.556
Output = Input - (Input Mod 0.01)
```

This will work with both positive and negative numbers